# Prevent Diagnostics.Process to close after finish

Tags: c#

I am running prompt commands using this function:

```
public static void Execute(string command)
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "/c " + command,
    };

     using (Process proc = Process.Start(psi))
        proc.WaitForExit();
}
```

But when the process ends i have no way to see the result of it in the console because it closes instantly. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Use /k instead of /c

Comment: @HansPassant awesome! this solved it!

Comment: You also could use a timeout, for sample: `process.WaitForExit(1000 * 60 * 5);` to wait up to five minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Put `Console.ReadKey();` at the end of the code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "cmd.exe",
        Arguments = "/c ",
    };

    using (Process proc = Process.Start(psi))
        proc.WaitForExit();

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```